# joomla: menus disappeared after migration from 1.0 to 1.5

Tags: joomla

Actually I try to migrate from **1.0 to 2.5.4** therefore I start form **1.0 to 1.5**. I installed Joomla 1.0 on my local **wamp** server to migrate Joomla 1.0 to Joomla 1.5 using [Upgrade from Joomla 1.0 to 1.5](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla15/joomla_upgrade.htm) although during this process it was showing lot of depreciated functions but after a while it is migrated with some less depreciated functions errors but the Site view does not showing menus..?

I googled and found [Menu items missing after upgrade v1.5.18 to v.1.5.20](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=430&t=535338&sid=93c8c5e760338bb5733b0c36602b08a5)

> The problem has to do with the way the new "menutype" input type is
>   used. It works great for new menus, but not for old ones with spaces.
>   As of right now, I recommend:

- Back up your site
- Export all of your DB tables using phpMyAdmin (checking Add Drop
  Tables on export screen)
- Open the SQL file that you exported
- Look for the SQL where "jos_menu_types" is (Note: if you used a
  different DB Prefix, it may not start with jos_).
- Example SQL you might find:

  **Code:**
  INSERT INTO `jos_menu_types` (`id`, `menutype`, `title`, `description`) VALUES(5, 'Right Menu', 'Right Menu', '');
- The first instance of "Right Menu" is the "menutype". This should NOT
  contain any spaces. In fact, I recommend make it lowercase,
  converting spaces to a hypen "-".
- Search the entire SQL file for all instances of "Right Menu" and
  change them to "right-menu".
- The tricky part here is that not all places need to be changed. For
  instance, you do not need to change the "second instance" in the
  example above, nor do you need to change the module title associated
  with this module.
- Once you have made your changes, import the SQL back up to your web
  site.

> If you have any issue, restore a copy of the original SQL file you
>   exported BEFORE you edited it and try again.
>
> I hope that helps. If you have any questions, please let me know.

but it does not fix the problem..

on left Mainmenu box it says:

> Warning: Parameter 1 to modMainMenuHelper::buildXML() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   E:\wamp\www\joomla_1.5\libraries\joomla\cache\handler\callback.php on
>   line 100

and Topmenu are completely disappeared.

I stuck here.. what will happen if I move forward ...!